# Jquery- How to change backgroundColor using prop method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I change the backgroundColor property value using the prop method?
I'm new to programming. :)

This is what I have,

```
$('ul').prop('backgroundColor','red');
```

I read the chapters on this book I'm reading and it is my understanding that I can change properties from the DOM using the prop method in jquery. I can change other DOM properties such as className. Why not backgroundColor? Writing this I also tried atr.

```
$('ul').attr('background-color','red');
```

In this case, attr does have access to CSS properties, correct? However when using the prop method, we do have access to some CSS properties? Why is backgroundColor created?

I know the best way to go about changing the background color would be to use the css method, in jquery that is. I just wanted to know if or not the prop or atr method can change the background color, and why not, if not. I believe this will give me a better understanding of the DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `.css()` i.e. `$('ul').css('background-color','red');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `backgroundColor` is nested property of `style` property of the element so [`.prop('backgroundColor','red');`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) won't works here.

Instead, you can set property by getting DOM element. In case there is multiple element then you need to iterate over them.

```js
$('div')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';

// if there is multiple elements

$('div').each(function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div>
```

---

Or use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to set any style property.

```js
$('div').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the nested part. I will go back and read more on style. Which leads my to another question, do all CSS properties have a "duplicate" in the DOM? I see list-style and listStyle. Thanks

Comment: @HugoPerea : you can't use `-` character in dot notation that's why it's using camel case.... both way it would work

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to manipulate the CSS properties.

```
$('ul').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('ul').attr('background-color','red');
```

does not work as the attribute is "style" and backgroundColor is a property of that.

You need to use:

```
     $('ul')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

When coding straight html you can specify inline css like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#00000"></div>
```

Therefore using jquery, you can leverage this feature by using the attr method.

```
$('div').attr('style','background-color:#00000;');
```

So in a way, yes you can alter css using the attr method. Because there is an "attribute" for style (css) in html and changing html attributes is basically what attr is for.